# restricted access on one of my pages in a site

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I am pulling out my hair figuring this issue out. I have a page in my site where it always asks for a username and password as if it's restricted, here's the [page](http://www.shopious.com/cara-bergabung). I have set restricted access to my other domain which is [here](http://dev.shopious.com). Here's my nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     dev.shopious.com;
        client_max_body_size 25M;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/dev.shopious.com.access_log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/dev.shopious.com.error_log warn;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        root            /home/yanrizal/shopious-dev/web;
        location / {
                try_files $uri /app_dev.php?$args;
        }
        index           app_dev.php index.php index.html;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;

        location ~ \.php($|/) {
                 set  $script $uri;
                set  $path_info "";

                if ($uri ~ "^(.+\.php)(/.*)") {
                        set  $script     $1;
                        set  $path_info  $2;
                }
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                keepalive_timeout 0;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;

        }

        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

        location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
                expires 1d;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires 1y;
                log_not_found off;
        }
    }
```

Why is it that if I remove the restricted on this config file it also resolved the restriction issue on this particular page? All the other pages on this site aren't restricted, just this particular page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to load an image from your dev site:

```
http://dev.shopious.com/bundles/shopiousmain/img/mau-daftar/Shopious-Desktop-3-foto-kategori.png
```

Notice the missing image in the section titled: `ONLINE SHOPPERS YANG NGGA PAKE ...`

Also, if you open dev tools in chrome and look at the console, you will see the error